# Is this web-service scenario an instance where REST is not appropriate?

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm designing a web service that parses a large document (150-200k) and returns some analytical data. The contents of the document are sensitive, and currently not persisted by the backend.

With a stateless REST web service, where all requests are idempotent, this would require every request to include the large document payload, which seems less than ideal.

Would a stateful alternative be a more appropriate design for this scenario, where a session is established after the initial document is POSTed? The client could then make further requests to endpoints which would provide differing analytical results, using the document in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it as a REST interface tacked onto a document storage service.

The document is stored temporarily. Perhaps it stays for 10 minutes or until released by the owner. The doc storage service returns a token allowing access to the document. But the token expires with the document timeout.

Then you only need REST services to ask questions about the document. Each call needs to include the token but can be repeated indefinitely and still get the same response.

You may want to cache certain information about each document. That's a performance issue.

You might want to consider how to encrypt the token in such a way that it can't be copied off the "wire" and used by a "bad guy(TM)".